# How do I get the colour of a point in a 3d plane THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

So im trying to simulate a sensor in THREE.js and what i would like to achieve it to get the colour of of the pixel i am pointing to using a Vector3 as my plane in 3d not 2d it is working fine when using a mouse however i woud like to give the code a point using x y and z axis rather than only x and y as my plane floor in x and z axis and y is a constant this code works with the mouse however when i try to switch the values with the points i want it does not give me the value expected.

```
function render() {
  renderer.setRenderTarget(rtTexture);
  renderer.clear();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);


  renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  var read = new Float32Array(4);

  renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(
    rtTexture,
    windowHalfX + mouseX,
    windowHalfY - mouseY,
    1,
    1,
    read
  );
  // console.log(windowHalfX + mouseX, "dsdsd", windowHalfY - mouseY);

  console.log("r:" + read[0] + "<br/>g:" + read[1] + "<br/>b:" + read[2]);
}
```

as i am trying to simulate a sensor i would like to be in control of the point i cant its colour value not what i am pointing too

Comment: You have some choices, but all of them lead back to using a [`Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster). Following examples you can find around the web, you can use a raycaster to query the scene for the `Mesh` below your cursor, and that result includes the 3D intersection point. From there you can get the color from the mesh's material, BUT _this is not necessarily the same as the pixel color due to shading_. The easiest way to get the rendered pixel color is still from the 2D result.

Comment: i have something similar to that already working where i get the value of the pixel however i would like to achieve this without the raycaster as i dont want the value to depend on the cursor but on the sensor which is a 3d object that i have simulated to act as a sensor so i need for the code to specify which point i am on rather than it being dependant on the cursor

Comment: Cursor position is just a 2D coordinate in screen-space, and you can certainly define a 2D coordinate without it being tied to the cursor. If you have a 3D coordinate, you can unproject it into a screen coordinate ([a common question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bthree.js%5D+world+coordinates+to+screen+coordinates)) so you can grab the pixel color value.