# getting pixel colour value from three.js scene

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

so im trying to get the colour of an image i added as texture and display the value of the colour however all the codes i have used print out values that do not represent what i want and i dont know the reason behind this, the last code i have tried is one that is uploaded my mrdoob it does display colour but just not the value i am expecting here is an image of my webpage with the scene inculded i would like to ge the value of the colour at the head of the robot

this is where i got my code https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/758

```
function colourSensorFunctionImage3() {
  var imagedata = getImageData( imgTexture.image );
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  toScreenPosition(cube2, camera);
var x = pixelX.toFixed(); 
var y = pixelY.toFixed();
console.log( x ,y)
//var color = getPixel( imagedata, x, y);
var color = getPixel( imagedata, -1214,  299 );


//console.log ( pixelX.toFixed(), pixelY.toFixed())

document.getElementById("Colour").innerHTML = color.r + " " + color.g + " " + color.b;
}

function getImageData( image ) {

  var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;

  var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
  context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );

  return context.getImageData( 0, 0, image.width, image.height );

}

function getPixel( imagedata, x, y ) {

  var position = ( x + imagedata.width * y ) * 4, data = imagedata.data;
 // console.log(position, data, data[position], data[position+1], data[position+2])
  return { r: data[ position ], g: data[ position + 1 ], b: data[ position + 2 ], a: data[ position + 3 ] };

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the colour of a point in a 3d plane THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354995/how-do-i-get-the-colour-of-a-point-in-a-3d-plane-three-js)

Comment: It should be var position = ( ( imagedata.width * y ) + x ) * 4; :) Here is a awesome reference! https://creative-coding.decontextualize.com/video/ (It's under "Working with pixel data from videos")